# how to insert record in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Can anyone help me on how to add new record in gridview in asp
here is my code:

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim drow As DataRow
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim x As Integer

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        drow = dt.NewRow
        drow("fname") = TextBox1.Text
        drow("mname") = TextBox2.Text
        drow("lname") = TextBox3.Text
        dt.Rows.Add(drow)

        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Page.IsPostBack = False Then
            binds()
        End If
    End Sub
    Protected Sub binds()

        dt.Columns.Add("fname")
        dt.Columns.Add("mname")
        dt.Columns.Add("lname")
        drow = dt.NewRow
        drow("fname") = TextBox1.Text
        drow("mname") = TextBox2.Text
        drow("lname") = TextBox3.Text
        dt.Rows.Add(drow)

        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub
End Class
```

when I click the button the error says that the fname does not belong to the table. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that all objects are disposed at the end of the page's lifecycle including your `DataTable`, `DataRow` and the ineteger. They will be initialized with their default values on every postback.

But you have this initialization code in `Page_Load`:

```
If Page.IsPostBack = False
    binds() ' which creates the table and adds the columns '
End If
```

The solution is not to use fields but local variables.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    binds()
End Sub

Private Sub binds()
    Dim drow As DataRow
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("fname")
    dt.Columns.Add("mname")
    dt.Columns.Add("lname")
    drow = dt.NewRow
    drow("fname") = TextBox1.Text
    drow("mname") = TextBox2.Text
    drow("lname") = TextBox3.Text
    dt.Rows.Add(drow)

    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks For the answer, but i found a way to my problem, Im using session now to add items in gridview.

Answer (score 0):

here is my code now.

Partial Class _Default

```
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Dim dcl As DataRowCollection
Dim drow As DataRow
Dim dt As New DataTable

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    binds()

End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Page.IsPostBack = False Then
        addcolumns()
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub addcolumns()

    dt.Columns.Add("fname")
    dt.Columns.Add("mname")
    dt.Columns.Add("lname")
    Session("dtInSession") = dt

End Sub
Protected Sub binds()

    If Session("dtInSession") IsNot Nothing Then
        dt = Session("dtInSession")
    End If

    drow = dt.NewRow
    drow("fname") = TextBox1.Text
    drow("mname") = TextBox2.Text
    drow("lname") = TextBox3.Text
    dt.Rows.Add(drow)

    Session("dtInSession") = dt
    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score -2):

```
## Heading ##
    public DataTable SearchStudents(string studFirstname)
    {
        logOBj.conn.Close();
        logOBj.conn.Open();

       logOBj.DA = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From STUDENT where studFirstname LIKE '%" + studFirstname + "%'", logOBj.conn);

       logOBj.DT = new DataTable();
       logOBj.DA.Fill(logOBj.DT);//data adapter fills the datatable

       return logOBj.DT;
    }
```